# How do I communicate to my boss about unfair competition in my workplace?

Tags: communication, competition

I've worked in this small company for 3 years. My company has no Human Resource Department. My boss handle almost everything except finance and sales. He rarely come to the workplace

Recently, my sales co-workers has unfair competition about their achievements. They're sisters working in the same workplace. They like to steal others sales customers and it seems like only they are working. They are making the most sales etc. The older sister is now promoted to a sales coordinator which makes things even worse. They are more and more arbitrary. Unfortunately, my boss seems to treat her as her favorite without knowing what really happens in the workplace.

How to tell my boss that the current environment is not okay with unhealthy competition? I afraid it will have impact on the future of the company.

Comment: What is your role in the organization?

Comment: I'm sales staff too.

Comment: Do you mean they're stealing your customers and presenting them as your own? And that the "unfair competition" is inside the company and hurting the company itself?

Comment: Yes. For example, when a customer calls the office and looks for me to ask something, they will take over the customer and not pass it on to me.

Comment: What is the impact of this? Is it a matter of taking undue credit, or is there a financial aspect to this (if you work on commission)? Also, are you in an "at will employment" culture, or do you have access to certain employee protection?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, you frame it in terms of the negative impact to the business.

I have to be blunt. Your boss does not care about fairness. They are not a referee at a sporting match. They care about results. They don't care who gets the sale done, if it gets done. Your example seems like they picked up the phone, heard the spoke with the customer and got it sorted. Maybe the customer never mentioned your name.

You have very vaguely mentioned that it will not be good for the future of the company, but you need to put that in concrete terms.

Maybe for example with some of the customers you had an upsell lined up, but that didn't eventuate because the customer wasn't able to get ahold of you. Maybe the customer haggled lower than what your previously agreed? Find some justification that it tied to the best interests of the business.

So it would probably be best to have a quiet chat with the boss, but be prepared for them to be dismissive.

I would recommend against rocking the boat too much, cause the sisters will certainly stick up for each other. One is a supervisor and a favourite of the boss too.

Pragmatically, it sounds to me like you have to close these sales and not give them an opportunity to steal them.